# why is it recommended to use else if among switch and if in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, if-statement, switch-statement

Why would be more convenient to do:

```
var cnt = $("#div1 p").length;
alert(cnt);
if (cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 20)      alert('10');
else if (cnt >= 21 && cnt <= 30) alert('21');
else if (cnt >= 31 && cnt <= 40) alert('31');
else alert('>41');
```

instead of:

```
switch (cnt) {
    case 1: ....
    case 2: ....
    case 3: ....
}
```

or even

```
var cnt = $("#div1 p").length;
alert(cnt);
if (cnt >= 10 && cnt <= 20)      alert('10');
if (cnt >= 21 && cnt <= 30) alert('21');
if (cnt >= 31 && cnt <= 40) alert('31');
else alert('>41');
```

so it seems that If there are lots of cases, the switch statement seems cleaner.
It's also nice when you have multiple values for which you want the same behavior - just using multiple "case" statements that fall through to a single implementation is much easier to read than a if( this || that || someotherthing || ... )

So what option is better for several cases?

Comment: 40 cases are cleaner than 4 ifs?!

Comment: _why is it recommended to use else if among switch and if in jquery_ - Where is this recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch` statement will take a lot of more comparisons for your purpose, since it can test just strict equivalence (`===`).

But the `if ... else if` structure is better since it stops the comparisons after the first true expression. It may be not suitable for some cases, but it does for yours.

Also, as a secondary advice, I suggest to put first the condition that you think have the highest chance to be true. For example:

```
if (age >= 18 && age < 60) { // Mainstream
    ...
} else if (age >= 12 && age < 18) { // Smart kids
    ...
} else if (age >= 60 && age < 99) { // Savvy old people
    ...
} else { // ... Aliens?!
    ...
}
```

This works best for mutually exclusive conditions, as in the above example. It may cause a mess if this isn't true:

```
var t = $(element);
if (t.is("div > p")) {
    ...
} else if (t.is("p")) {
    ...
}
```

The above example **is not** the same thing as

```
var t = $(element);
if (t.is("p")) {
    ...
} else if (t.is("div > p")) {
    ...
}
```

because `t.is("div > p")` and `t.is("p")` are *not* mutually exclusive. Try to change the conditions to be like that, for example: `t.is("p")` => `t.is(":not(div) > p")`.

switch is usually best for single-case comparisons, for example:

```
var d = new Date().getDay(), t;
switch (d) {
    case 0: t = "Sunday"; break;
    case 1: t = "Monday"; break;
    case 2: t = "Tuesday"; break;
    ...
}
```

is definitely more readable and compact than

```
var d = new Date().getDay(), t;
if (d === 0) t = "Sunday";
else if (d === 1) t = "Monday";
else if (d === 2) t = "Tuesday";
...
```

The only thing I heard against the use of `switch` for single-case comparison is that once `switch` was quite slow on several Javascript engines. This isn't the case anymore for a couple of years, though.

Comment: so lots of if{}if{}if{} are same that swith rigth, only if{}else{} will stop if condition is satisfied

Comment: @cMinor That's right. Go for it if the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Using `else if` instead of several `if` statements is basically a good idea if they exclude each other:

```
if(x >= 10 && x <= 20) { 
    ... 
} else if (x >= 21 && x <= 30) { ... }
```

This way the second `if` will only be checked if the first one is false. This one is a bad idea:

```
if(x >= 10 && x <= 20) { ... }
if (x >= 21 && x <= 30) { ... } // will be checked also if the 1st if is true
```

`switch` can hardly be used for value ranges (`x >= 21 && x <= 30`), but is more comfortable for checking for a lot of unique values (`x===10`, `x===11` etc.). `switch` will stop it's execution after the first `break`:

```
switch(x){
    case 1:
        console.log("one");
    case 2:
        console.log("two");
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log("three");
        break;
}
```

Output depending on the values of `x`:

- 1: `one two`
- 2: `two`
- 3: `three`
- 4: (no output)

More information about the switch statement can be found on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the ternary operator : test ? VAlue_If_True_Statement : value_if_false_Statement; it's a great way to refactoring your code.